# Calculating Expectation from CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

The CDF is defined as follows:

$$
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,\qquad x \lt 0 \\[3ex]
\frac{x^2}{18}+\frac{x}{6}, \quad 0 \le x \lt 3\\[2ex]
1,\qquad x \ge 3
\end{cases}
$$

And i have to calculate the Expectation.

I tried to calculate it in following way:

$\int_0^3{f(x)(\frac{x^2}{18}+\frac{x}{6}})$

where $f(x)$ is the PDF = $\frac{x}{9}+\frac{1}{6}$ which is  derivate of CDF.

Now as a result, when i calculate the integral i get $\frac{1}{2}$ which is incorrect. What i´m doing wrong / missing here ?

Comment: Expectation is defined as $E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$, where $f(x)$ is the PDF for $X$. You've mistakenly substituted $F(x)$ for $x$, i.e. you've calculated $\int_{0}^{3}f(x)F(x)dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X\ge 0$ as in your case, then the expectation can be directly calculated from the CDF by the formula $$E[X]=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))dx$$ which in that case yields  $$E[X]=\int_{0}^{3}1-\left(\frac{x^2}{18}+\frac{x}{6}\right)dx+\int_{3}^{+\infty}(1-1)dx$$